# What are the sets $S_n=\omega-n$ called?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, ordinals

What are the sets $S_n$ where $S_n:=\omega-n$ called?

I explain better: if ordinals are defined in this way

$0=\varnothing$

$1=\{\varnothing\}=\{0\}$

$2=\{0,1\}$

$n=\{0,1,..,n-1\}$

$\omega=\{0,1,2,..\}$

1. What are the sets $S_n=\omega-n=\{n,n+1,n+2,...\}$ called?
2. For every $S_n$, $|S_n|=\aleph_0$? Why can't there exist an $S_n$ with a finite number of elements (I can think about it in my mind but I don't see a way to find which are those elements)?
3. Does $S_{\omega}=\varnothing$? (Intuitively I would say yes, because since the elements of $n\cup S_n$ are the elements of $\omega$, $\omega -\omega=\varnothing$ because if I take from the naturals all the naturals I have the empty set.)

Maybe what I said has no meaning, someone can explain better this, what I don't see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The *sequence* $(1, 2, \ldots, n - 1)$ is an initial segment of the *sequence* $(1, 2, 3, \ldots)$, and $(n, n+ 1, n + 1 \ldots)$ is an end-segment. I suppose you could call the set $\{n, n+ 1, n + 1 \ldots\}$ an end-segment too, taking the usual order as understood.
2. Why can't there exist a $S_n = \{n, n +1, n + 2 \ldots\}$ with a finite number of elements? Because there is an obvious bijection between the elements of $S_n$ and $\mathbb{N}$ (map $n + k \in S_n$ to $k \in \mathbb{N}$): so, by definition, $S_n$ is countably infinite.
3. What is $S_{\omega}$? You have only defined $S_n$ for finite $n$. If the idea is that $S_{\omega} =_{\mathrm{def}} \omega - \omega$ and the 'minus' still indicates set difference, then yes, $S_{\omega}$ is empty.

Comment: Yes, i understand point 2) i had not considered the "bijection" point of view (and was obvious looking better the set $S_n$ ) it just is the codomain of the function $f(k)=n+k$ thak you for the answer!

Answer (score 6):

1. I would probably call them *final segments of $\omega$*, but I don't think I've seen these sets referred to as anything in particular before.
2. Since $S_n \subseteq \omega$ then $S_n$ is either finite or countably infinite.  If it were finite, then $\omega$ would be the union of two finite sets, which is absurd!
3. If you define $S_\omega$ to be $\omega \setminus \omega$ (in analogy to $S_n$), then, yes, $S_\omega = \emptyset$.  If you define $S_\omega$ to be $\bigcap_{n < \omega} S_n$, then again $S_\omega = \emptyset$, since $n \notin S_{n+1} \supseteq S_\omega$ for all $n \in \omega$.

Comment: The argument of the continue intersection is very clear and is great because $S_n \cap S_m=S_{max(n,m)}$, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @MphLee: You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

I am not awareness a particular name. As a whole, this collection is the set of end segments/tails of $\omega$.

If I had to give these sets a name, I woe probably say that $S_n$ is the "$n$th tail of $\omega$".

These are all infinite because otherwise $n\cup S_n$ is the union of two finite sets - impossible.

Comment: Oh yea, now i undertand well how is not possible for finite $n$, anyways if exist a $S_\alpha$ finite that mean that $\alpha$ is an infinite ordinal that is not $\omega$..

Comment: Yes. It means $\sup S_\alpha$ is a successor ordinal.

Comment: mmh sorry i can't follow you'r last affermation, $supS_\alpha$ exists in $S_\alpha$ (and so in $\omega$)? I was thinking that such  $S_\alpha$ can't exist becuase it must have the bigger natural number in it, and evry infinite ordinal $\alpha\subsetneq\omega$ is absurd , after that (your answers had convinced me of the impossibility) i guess I made more confusion in my mind with my own words xD.

Comment: MphLee, clearly $S_\alpha$ for $\alpha\geq\omega$ is empty. Which is finite, and I guess that's just fine. But if you generalize this notion of $\alpha$-th tail of an ordinal $\delta$, then $S_\alpha^\delta$ (the $\alpha$-th tail of $\delta$) is finite (and non-empty) if and only if $\delta$ is a successor ordinal and $\delta=\alpha+n$ for some $n>0$.

Comment: In fact $\omega$ is not a successor ordinal. Anyways i find a bit "sad" that can't not exist an $\alpha$-tail such that, for example $|S_\alpha^\omega |=1$.

I say this because somewhere in my "immagination" i can see (construct) an object like this. Maybe my mind can do that because is not using axiomatic rules (which we are using in set theory) aka I'm thinking wrong, or maybe is a limitation of the fact that we create ordinals with a recursive definition and my (our) brain can handle an "actual infinity" not builded "by steps" (recursively)? Have this any sense?

Comment: That would be $\omega+1$. The first ordinal that is a successor of a limit ordinal. The idea with recursion is that from any point along the process of the construction, to the "minimal" point from which you began there can only be a finite number of steps to unwind. That is, every decreasing sequence is finite. I think this is why so many things are defined by recursion and proved by induction, and this is why we can handle those sort of objects slightly better.

Comment: Great, that made me more clear the point of induction/recursion in mathematics.