# Intersection of infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $B_k=\{k, k+1, k+2,...\}$
Then why is it that  $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}B_k=\emptyset$  ?
Is it not the case that $\infty$ is in every set?

Comment: In the expression
$$B_k=\{k, k+1, k+2,...\},$$
what do the dots mean precisely?

Comment: $B_k$ for $k \in \Bbb N$?

Comment: Look this question. Here you can find the answer to your question 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352090/what-are-the-sets-s-n-omega-n-called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $B_k\subseteq\Bbb N$, then note that $\infty\notin\Bbb N$. So $\infty\notin B_k$ for any $k$.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the $k$'s are natural numbers or real numbers, in which case $\infty$ is simply not a number, and not a member of any of those sets. Moreover, for each $k$ you can find an $l$ such that $k\notin B_l$ by simply taking $l=k+1$; this alone is sufficient to tell you that there is no number that is in all of these sets.